# Use an MS SQL Server function as a column alias

Tags: sql, winforms, sql-server-2005

I've created a function for retrieving the translations of database columns in MS SQL Server 2005, depending on the selected language code (e.g. 'el-GR'). The function itself works correctly, but I am unable to use its result as the Alias for the retrieved columns.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT
    tblAuditors.[Full Name] as dbo.GetLocalizedGridTranslation('Auditor Name', @languageCode)
FROM tblCompanyAuditors
```

Does anyone know how I can trick the SQL Server into allowing me to use the function as an Alias name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the alias in brackets `[]`:

```
SELECT 
   [dbo.GetLocalizedGridTranslation('Auditor Name', @languageCode)] = tblAuditors.[Full Name]
FROM tblAuditors
```

Apart from that, is it a typo that you've queried a table `tblCompanyAuditors` but the column is from table `tblAuditors`?

**Edit**: I've only just noticed that the column alias itself should be the result of a function.

Does that make sense? An alias is a column for all records, and a function will be executed on every record. If that's a stored-procedure i would recommend to store the result in a variable and use that as column alias in dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @column_alias VARCHAR(30)
SET @column_alias = dbo.GetLocalizedGridTranslation('Auditor Name', @languageCode);

-- Use dynamic SQL
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT tblAuditors.[Full Name] AS ' + @column_alias + ' FROM tblAuditors'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: My bad, I left out the inner join for clarity but forgot to change the table name!
I tried wrapping it in brackets, but that only resulted in using the whole expression as the alias (without executing the sql function)...

Comment: @Themos: I'm not sure if i understood the requirement correctly. So you want to have a dynamic alias that is the result of a function? Does that make sense? An alias is a column for all records, and a fucntion will be executed on every record. If that's a stored-procedure i would recommend to store the result in a variable and use that as column alias.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want, a dynamic alias depending on the localization language! I've tried passing the result into a variable and using the variable as the alias, but the SQL server wouldn't let me do that either...

Comment: @Themos: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

i had to change it from varchar(1000) to nvarchar(1000) and also enclosed the alias variable in brackets to get it to work, this is exactly the result I was after! However, is there a way to do it without using a dynamic sql? (because I would like to implement this in a large number of stored procedures, which are much more complex...)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... anyways, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need to use dynamic SQL

ie

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(max)
 select @sql = 'SELECT tblAuditors.[Full Name] as ['
      + dbo.GetLocalizedGridTranslation('Auditor Name', @languageCode) 
      + '] FROM tblCompanyAuditors'

 exec sp_executesql @sql
```